# Usage of "prevalent" in reference to a disease

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Is it ok to use word 'prevalent' in the following sentence:

> Flu is very prevalent in the third world countries, that nobody cares about it.

Comment: **Very** doesn't sit well with **that** in the sentence. Consider these sentences -> 
Variation 1: _Flu is so prevalent in third world countries that nobody cares about it_.
Variation 2: _Flu is highly/very prevalent in third world countries, so nobody cares about it_.

Comment: No. 'Prevalent' merely says that it exists, and cannot have an intensifier like 'very.' Use *widespread* instead, or another similar word. At most, you could say "highly prevalent."

Comment: +Kris, technically, the language of statistics says that *possibility*, as opposed to *probability*, is not quantifiable. Probability/likelihood is the quantification of possibility. Therefore, technically, are people not allowed to say "*very possible*" ?? The beauty of English is the laxity, ambiguity and redundancy allowed in its colloquial use.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Sure, very much possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "prevalent" is suitable in this sentence, but as Manish has stated it's better to rephrase this sentence. There is nothing wrong with the choice of words.

As per the Oxford advanced learner's dictionary;

***that exists or is very common at a particular time or in a particular place***

A disease is something which is prevalent for a particular time period unless it is chronic.